# IE8 Error: is null or not an object, but can still trace/console log out

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer-8

I'm getting an JS error in IE8 but for the life of me cannot seem to find a reason to why this error is firing.

I'm referencing a JSON file that has been requested and parsed with jQuery's `$.getJSON()`. Once that is done, I use an event (pub/sub) that is fired and from there do what ever I need to do with the parsed JSON file.

All good until, IE8 throws an error on the `imgPath` variable declaration (below). I'm loading an image into a `<img>` tag through the `src` attribute.

```
//This is function is inside a object
IE8_loadImage: function($root, data) {
        var self       = this,
            $comp      = $root.data('comp').parent,
            $imgHolder = $root.data('comp').IE8holder,
            imgPath    = $root.data('json')[data.scene][data.convo]['ie8Img'];

        console.log(typeof $root.data('json')); //outputs to 'object'
        console.log(imgPath);                   //outputs to 'images/1-0.jpg'
        console.log(typeof imgPath);            //output 'string'
        console.log(typeof data.scene);         //output 'string'
        console.log(typeof data.convo);         //output 'string'

        //Set the source
        $imgHolder.css('z-index', 5).attr('src', imgPath);
    },
```

The odd thing is that I can console.log out the `imgPath` variable and get the intended result from the JSON.

The JSON (checked on [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)) file is as follows:

```
{
"demo": {
    "scene1": {
        "c0": {
            "text": "Lorem ipsum Tempor magna nisi non enim fugiat do dolor dolore esse aliquip irure ullamco cillum dolor reprehenderit eiusmod dolore irure commodo et reprehenderit voluptate dolore Ut in Duis tempor tempor esse et Duis enim.",
            "ie8Img": "images/1-0.jpg",
            "audio": { 
                "source": "audio/s1-1.mp3",
                "autoplay": "true"
            }
        },
        "c1": {
            "text": "Lorem ipsum Tempor magna nisi non enim fugiat do dolor dolore esse aliquip irure ullamco cillum dolor reprehenderit eiusmod dolore irure commodo et reprehenderit voluptate dolore Ut in Duis tempor tempor esse et Duis enim.",
            "ie8Img": "images/1-1.jpg",
            "audio": {
                "source": "",
                "autoplay": "false"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea, or just a second pair of eyes on why this could be happening – would be awesome! Thanks.

**Edit:**
The error message is `data(...)[...][...].ie8Img is null or not an object`

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Can you post the result of all those `console.log` with the Error? Maybe from the order of the prints something can be clearer. Looking at the code as is I cannot see anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue that I was having a double callback firing with a scrollTop animation:

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $elem.offset().top - offset
}, self.options.speed, function() {
    // Callback function here...
    callback();
});
```

So tracing through my code with the debugger, this event was firing twice in IE8 for both 'html', and 'body'. So so I ended up using a `.promise()` to fire the callback only once after completion of the animation. Since it was firing twice, the variables were being updated too quickly.